# able to save fields into a variable and use into queryset.value() ? django

Tags: python, django, variables, django-queryset

I know that when we call `querysets`, we can use `values()` to get fields needed such as `values('name', 'other_model__title')` and such.

But I am wondering if it is possible to save it into a variable for example:

```
value_fields = ('name', 'other_model__title')
model.objects.filter().values(value_fields)
```

I tried this already which failed, also tried using `list` instead of `tuple` which failed too, giving me error saying `object has no attribute split`

Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. this is for django 1.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, you can "*unpack*" an iterable into *position* parameters in Python, by using a *single asterisk* (`*`) in the function call, like:

```
value_fields = ('name', 'other_model__title')
model.objects.all().values(*value_fields)
#                          ^ asterisk
```

If you call a function `f(..)` with an iterable `xs` like `f(*xs)`, then Python will call it like `f(x1, x2, xn)` (with `xi` an individual element of the `xs` iterable). Since you stored the parameters in a tuple (a tuple *is* an iterable), it will thus call the `.values(..)` function with `.values('name', 'other_model__title')`).

By using two asterisks (like `f(**some_dict)`), you can unpack dictionary-like objects into *named* parameters.

Comment: omg, that's right.  Totally forgot the `*` to unpack it.  Kept thinking it'll do it itself.  Nice nice, thanks for this.  Does the unpack actually uses the `split` which is why it's giving the error of split? because I do remember long ago seeing some error with `unpack` instead of saying `split`

Comment: @Tsuna: If I recall correctly, it aims to process the tuple as if it was a string, and it for example aims to split on the `'__'` parts, to understand that `'foo__bar'` is an indirect field (the `.bar` of the `.foo` reference). But the unpack itself does not use `.split()`, it is however possible that when *processing* the parameters, errors occur.

Comment: got it , that does make sense. Really thanks for the help :D

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, how can I use it in `Model.*key.field.verbose_name`?